# How to set an Enum's numeric value

Tags: c#, reflection, enums

Is there a way to set the underlying value of an enum (e.g. via reflection)?
And what will happen if there is no matching enum entry for the set value?

Bonus: What would be the implications for someone using the enum after it was set to an "invalid" value?

Thanks!

Edit: (Use-Case)
One use-case would be for testing purposes.
Assume you have a protocol with a message type field represented by a enum, transferred as a byte in the protocol.
Now what if I want to test some message type field values which are invalid, aka not defined and thus not part of the enum.

Bonus 2:
Hoiw would that cast look like if the enum type is dynamic as opposed to fixed. E.g. assume you get handed a enum type object and want to set its underlying value to 1.

Comment: Why you want to change the value of enum using reflection? Can you explain the use case you are trying to handle?

Comment: Yes. Just try casting an `int` to an enumerated type and see what happens.  And, what happens if you set it to a value that's not specified by the type? Well, it gets set. Your program needs to deal with it if you allow that to happen

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya: edited with a use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to answer ***all*** of your questions

**Given**

```
public enum SomeEnum
{
    Bob,
    Blip
}
```

---

> Is there a way to set the underlying value of an enum

Yes..

```
myEnum = (SomeEnum)1; ///  = Blip
```

---

> And what will happen if there is no matching enum entry for the set
> value?

Nothing...

```
myEnum = 3;

If(myEnum == SomeEnum.Bob)
   // never gets hit
```

---

> What would be the implications for someone using the enum after it was
> set to an "invalid" value?

Same as above

**Consider**

```
SomeEnum myEnum;
    
myEnum = (SomeEnum)1;
Console.WriteLine(myEnum);
    
myEnum = (SomeEnum)3;
Console.WriteLine(myEnum);
```

**Output**

```
Blip
3
```

Though you could imagine a situation where someone ranges checks an enum

```
var myEnum = (SomeEnum)3;

switch (myEnum)
{
    case SomeEnum.Bob:
       break;
    case SomeEnum.Blip:
       break;
    default:
       throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
 }
```

In which case an exception will get thrown

---

> Now what if I want to test some message type field values which are
> invalid, aka not defined and thus not part of the enum.

you could use the [`Enum.IsDefined Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.isdefined?view=net-5.0)

> Returns a Boolean telling whether a given integral value, or its name
> as a string, exists in a specified enumeration.

**Example**

```
if(!Enum.IsDefined(SomeWeirdReflectedType, someValue))
  ...
```

---

> How would that cast look like if the enum type is dynamic as opposed
> to fixed

You can use [`Enum.ToObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.toobject?view=net-5.0) convert an integer to an *enum* value at runtime

> Converts a specified integer value to an enumeration member.

**Example**

```
var someEnumType = typeof(SomeEnum);

var asd = Enum.ToObject(someEnumType, 1);

Console.WriteLine(asd);
Console.WriteLine(asd.GetType());
```

**Output**

```
Blip
ConsoleApp1.Program+SomeEnum
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast!
One last question: what if I have a dynamic enum, e.g. I get a object with ```IsEnum==true```.
How would that cast look like?

Comment: @Wall-E I am guessing what you mean by dynamic is actually a nullable enum ?

Comment: No not a nullable one. See my edit, paraphrased: Assume you determined the enum type dynamically (e.g. via reflection). How to cast the value you want to set to the determined (enum) type?
Aka I can't write ```myEnum = (MyEnum) 3```, since I don't know the Enum Typ a priori - but rather at runtime.